# Is it possible to share the batchId of a foreachBatch between 2+ streams?

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, azure-databricks

The problem that I am facing is that my process relies on the batchId as some sort of control of what is ready to the second stage of the pipeline. So it wil only go to the second stage if the first stage (batch) is completed.

**I want to make sure I can improve speed when needed by attaching more streams to the same data source.** <<-- (That is why this is not a duplicated post)

I also want to guarantee that in case of something goes wrong, the stream can continue from where it stopped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup a starting point for the batchId of foreachBatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58955738/how-to-setup-a-starting-point-for-the-batchid-of-foreachbatch)

Comment: This is not duplicated, on this question, I want to share the batchId with 2 streams.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on _"attaching more streams to the same data source"_? How could batchId improve speed of a query?

Comment: My data source is an eventhub, if the workload is too large, I want to attach more streams to the event hub, so more data gets processed at the same time. However my pipeline relies on the batchId, so I want to somehow make it work

Comment: In such a case, you simply need more tasks and executors so you can keep up with the input data. Streaming queries don't share batch IDs.